# js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);

Tags: html, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, automation

```html
<li class="tree-node">
    <div id="WLOBJ_mmuX_left_row_0e6d" class="default-row, no-border-row" style="height:22px">
        <table class="default-row, no-border-row" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width:100%;height:22;">
            <tbody>
                    <tr>
                    <td class="gridcell " align="center" style="width:25;">
                        <input id="WLOBJ_mmuX_rowchk" type="hidden" value="N" style="width:10px" name="WLOBJ_mmuX_rowchk"/>
                        <input id="chk_WLOBJ_mmuX_rowchk" class="chk" type="checkbox" onclick="GRID_CORE.setcheckboxvalue(RSYS_GRID_CACHE.get('WLOBJ_mmuX'), this);(RSYS_GRID_CACHE.get('WLOBJ_mmuX').selectrow(this));" style="text-align:center" name="chk_WLOBJ_mmuX_rowchk"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</li>

<li class="tree-node">
    <div id="WLOBJ_mmuX_left_row_1K85" class="default-row, no-border-row" style="height:22px">
        <table class="default-row, no-border-row" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width:100%;height:22;">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="gridcell " align="center" style="width:25;">
                        <input id="WLOBJ_mmuX_rowchk" type="hidden" value="N" style="width:10px" name="WLOBJ_mmuX_rowchk"/>
                        <input id="chk_WLOBJ_mmuX_rowchk" class="chk" type="checkbox" onclick="GRID_CORE.setcheckboxvalue(RSYS_GRID_CACHE.get('WLOBJ_mmuX'), this);(RSYS_GRID_CACHE.get('WLOBJ_mmuX').selectrow(this));" style="text-align:center" name="chk_WLOBJ_mmuX_rowchk"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</li>
```

```
WebElement element= driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@id='WLOBJ_mmuX_left_row_0e6d']/table[@class='default-row, no-border-row']/tbody/tr/td[@class='gridcell ']/input[@id='chk_WLOBJ_mmuX_rowchk']"));
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

**is not working**

Comment: How is it not working? Do you encounter any exceptions etc?

Comment: Welcome to SO. As explained in the guides, [please don't just say your code isn't working](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: How can I use this: WebElement element= driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@id='WLOBJ_mmuX_left_row_0e6d']/table[@class='default-row, no-border-row']/tbody/tr/td[@class='gridcell ']/input[@id='chk_WLOBJ_mmuX_rowchk']"));
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);

but then it clicks on the right side (instead of center or left)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the class attributes from Xpath.
Try the following:

> WebElement element=
>   driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@id='WLOBJ_mmuX_left_row_0e6d']/table/tbody/tr/td/input[2]"));

Why do you need to use

> js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);

You can just use

> element.click();

Selenium can't recognize "," in the @class="abc,def" attribute.Let me know if this helped you solve the problem.